# How to check multiple kafka topics exists via Kafka client (consumer or producer)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Does Kafka client provide a way to only check the existence of some topics that the app cares about?

The reason is the app diagnostic endpoint uses this check to make sure 3rd party integration is working as expected.

I would like to expect there is an API for `Boolean topicExists(foo1, foo2, foo3)`.

If there is no API supported directly, it seems that I have to use `listTopics`, but it returns lots of internal topics I have to filter out like `__consumer_offsets`. It is ok but not very nice. :(

```
  val topicMustHave = Set(...)
  val allTopics = consumer.listTopics().keySet().asScala

  println(allTopics.intersect(topicsMustHave) == topicsMustHave)
```

I wonder if there is a better way to check multiple topics exist?

Comment: Hi ! I think this may be duplicating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572023/checking-the-existence-of-topic-in-kafka-before-creating-in-java/30600025#30600025 (at least the answer seems to be the same) ?

Comment: Thanks guys, `adminClient.describeTopics(topicsMustHave.asJava)` is the one I am looking for. Cheers. I will close this question.